# Printing model summaries to file in R

Tags: r

Iv'e made progress in understanding map functions and dividing dataframes to subgroups with this awesome community.

I am now trying to iterate over each model I have put together, and print it (Later into a file ) With all the summary of the model.
It works over a single dataframe but not in a map setting.

This is what iv'e tried :

```
library(jtools)
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

nested <- mtcars %>% nest (data = -c(cyl,am))

t1 <- nested %>%  
  mutate (
    fit = map(data, ~ lm(mpg ~ hp, data= .x)),
    sum = map(fit, ~summary(fit))) 

x1<- lm(mpg ~ hp, data=mtcars)
paste("this is test" , print (summ(x1)))

t1 %>% map2(fit, sum , ~ paste("this is a test" , print(fit), print(sum)))
```

EDIT
Thanks for the help. Now i'm trying to print multiple values using pmap. 
I have two issues - models not printing in a human way (as a list)
and pmap not working.

This is what iv'e tried

```
purrr::map2(t1$fit, t1$sum , ~ paste("this is a test" , summ(.x), print(.y)))

t1 %>% 
   pmap_df(list(.$cyl, .$am, .$fit), print)
```

EDIT 2: 
This works perfectly and it is exactly what iv'e wanted. If you have any input or  suggestions to an HTML format that can include some plots I would be Happy..

```
print_model <- function (df) {
  sink("output.txt")
for(i in seq(nrow(df))) {
  cat("\nThis model consists of\n") 
  print(paste 
        ("Number of Cyls:", df$cyl[[i]], 
          "Number of am", df$am[[i]]))
  print(summ(df$fit[[i]]))
  cat('\n End of model ************* \n')
} 
sink()  
}

print_model(t1)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To refer individual values in `map2` you can use `.x` and `.y`

```
purrr::map2(t1$fit, t1$sum , ~ paste("this is a test" , .x, .y))
```

---

To print it in a human-readable way I think it is better to use `for` loop.

```
library(jtools)

for(i in seq(nrow(t1))) {
   cat("\nthis is a test") 
   print(summ(t1$fit[[i]]))
   cat('\n')
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and if i want to use multiple values and not just two? Like adding the cyl and am data for each model?

Comment: For more than 2 values you can use `pmap`.

Comment: Thanks. Final question- This way print a list with the (c) , How can I make it humanly printable ? This is what iv'e tried `purrr::map2(t1$fit, t1$sum , ~ paste("this is a test" , summ(.x), print(.y)))`

Comment: I think for better control using `for` loop is much easier. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks. It seems more readable. There is sometimes bias against for loops, from what iv'e been able to read in R world